# Not loading correct images in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I just put a UIImageView and assign the image `bgImage.png` from the XIB Inspector. I added all the images in correct dimensions but the image is not loading according to the device.

```
bgImage.png (320 x 480)

bgImage@2x.png (640 x 960)

bgImage-568h@2x.png (640 x 1136)

bgImage-667h@2x.png (750 x 1334)

bgImage-736h@3x.png (1242 x 2208)
```

I dont want to use any category.
Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: How you know that the image is not loading according to the device?

Comment: Because I mark each image with a name on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your images as device specific through Image Asset.

Follow it

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/CustomizingImageSets.html

[image]

Comment: This is not a proper answer to the question. The question is that the images are not loading according to the device width and height.

Comment: Please see in image asset every image has 3 size. put your bgImage.png here by selecting the image in image asset.